# Why does sizeof(char + char) return 4?

Tags: c, char, sizeof

```
char  a, b;     
printf("%d", sizeof(a+b));
```

What will printf write to the screen?

I thought because sizeof(char)=1, that sizeof(a+b) will be also 1, but it turned out to be 4. I don't understand this, why does it write 4 if we are adding two chars?

Comment: What are you expecting? What did you read about the `sizeof` operator?

Comment: I expected it to return 1. I know it returns the size of a type or variable in bytes, more exactly number of chars that can fit there.

Comment: `a+b` is an integer evaluation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Size of character ('a') in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172943/size-of-character-a-in-c-c)

Comment: @BoPersson not a duplicate: `'a'` is an `int` already, but this question is about integer promotion of `char`s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C language operands of almost all arithmetic operators are subjected to implicit conversions called *usual arithmetic conversions* or, in this case, *integer promotions*. Operands of type `char` are promoted to type `int` and the actual addition is performed within the domain of `int` (or `unsigned int`, depending on the properties of `char` on that platform). So your `a + b` is actually interpreted as `(int) a + (int) b`. The result has type `int` and `sizeof(int)` is apparently 4 on your platform. That 4 is what you see.

And don't use `%d` to `printf` the result of `sizeof`. The result of `sizeof` has type `size_t`, while `%d` requires an `int` argument. So, either use the proper format specifier

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a+b));
```

or at least cast the argument if you are sure it fits

```
printf("%d\n", (int) sizeof(a+b));
```

Comment: Never heard of _integral promotions_.

Comment: @chux - it's the old C90 term - the formal standard term is integer promotions.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094412/what-is-the-difference-between-integral-promotion-and-balancing-in-c) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660758/integral-promotion) for more

Comment: @Chris I see: -->  "Integral promotions" is the old C90 term, the formal standard term is integer promotions.

Comment: Thank you, what would sizeof(a+b) return if a and b are float, and sizeof(float)=4? Will it promote/demote it or will it remain in float?

Comment: @Nebeski suggest you try that.

Comment: It returned 4, so I guess it stays in float.

Comment: @Nebeski: `float` is not promoted. Back in some ancient pre-standard version of C `float` used to be unconditionally promoted to `double`. But the idea was abandoned before the release of C89/90. In standard C `float` is not promoted to `double` in such expressions. (When passing arguments to functions with undeclared parameters `float` is implicitly converted to `double` though.)

Comment: @AnT, `float` is promoted to `double` only in case of one `double` appearing as the other operator in an arithmetic operator, and when passing a `float` as a parameter to a function with unspecified parameter type (incomplete or vararg).  I haven't heard about this to be abandoned somewhat.  At least, I'm programming with that assumption in mind without having warned of it to have changed.

Comment: @Luis Colorado: See "C Reference Manual" by Dennis Ritchie - one of the first C language "specs". It explicitly says *"6.2 Float and double. All floating arithmetic in C is carried out in double precision; whenever a float appears in an expression it is lengthened to double by zero padding
its fraction"*. (https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/cman.pdf) Moreover, if I'm not mistaken, the first edition of K&R C also included this rule.

Comment: Also, see the reference to "C Primer" in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13425012/187690, which implies that unconditional promotion of `float` to `double` was indeed present in K&R.

Comment: @AnT, yes... that's right, but that has been dropped a lot of time ago, as many architectures can work without promoting all `float`s to `double`s.  I think my observation was dated from ANSI spec onwards, as it deals with parameters not specifically declared as `float` (the case of varargs and unspecified parameter prototypes of the form `type func();`. Allow me some possible margin of mistake, as I don't have K&R in front of me and I speak from my (poor) memory.

Answer (score 6):

This is not the same as `sizeof(char)`, the argument (*i.e. the result of the addition*) is promoted to `int` so `sizeof(a + b)` is in fact equivalent to `sizeof(int)`. If you cast the result to `char` it will be what you expect. Also, the correct format specifier for `sizeof` result which is `size_t` is `%zu` and not `%d`.

Try

```
printf("%zu", sizeof((char) (a + b)));
```