# why this sizeof(c+a) is giving 4 byte instead of 3

Tags: c, char, int, sizeof, short

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   short int a;
   char c;
   printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(a),sizeof(c),sizeof(c+a));
}
```

In this sizeof a is 2 byte size of char is 1 byte but i add them up it is giving 4 byte. what it is doing inside the expression to make it 4

Comment: Aside: `%d` ==> `%zu`

Comment: how on earth is this getting so many votes?

Comment: Yeah... That's puzzling... Given that the expression `sizeof(c+a)` is a nonsensical and useless by itself. Well, I guess some people are just surprised by the results as the OP is.

Comment: @EugeneSh. IMO it's actually an interesting question that gets into the nuances of the integer conversion rules.  As in, "Why isn't the output 2?"  Because offhand, you'd think `short + char` should be a `short`, right?

Comment: @Andrew I would even agree with you if I hadn't seen every third question on SO about the same effect and formulated much better.

Comment: to start, the operator: `sizeof` returns a `size_t` which is further defined as `long unsigned int`.   So the `%d` format specifiers are not correct.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings: (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does sizeof(char + char) return 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300925/why-does-sizeofchar-char-return-4)

Answer (score 11):

Adding a `short int` to a `char` results in an `int`, which apparently is 4 bytes on your system.

This is a case if "integer promotion".  See [In a C expression where unsigned int and signed int are present, which type will be promoted to what type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280663/in-a-c-expression-where-unsigned-int-and-signed-int-are-present-which-type-will) for an explanation.  The rules are rather confusing, but the answers there  explain it rather well.

Per **6.3.1.8  Usual arithmetic  conversions** of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), the actual conversion rule is:

> If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is
>   needed.
>
> Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have
>   unsigned integer  types,  the  operand  with  the  type  of  lesser 
>   integer  conversion  rank  is converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has 
>   rank  greater  or equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other 
>   operand,  then  the  operand  with signed  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned integer
>   type.
>
> Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can
>   represent all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type, then the  operand  with  unsigned  integer  type  is 
>   converted  to  the  type  of  the operand with signed integer type.
>
> Otherwise,   both   operands   are   converted   to   the   unsigned
>   integer   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type.

The result is 4, because, as @WeatherVane noted in the comments:

5.1.2.3 para 11 EXAMPLE 2 *In executing the fragment* `char c1, c2; /* ... */ c1 = c1 + c2;` *the "integer promotions" require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to int size and then add the two ints and truncate the sum.* But there is no truncation here because the destination is unknown.

Comment: Are you certain that it is promoting to an int and not a short? (Not saying you are wrong, I am just trying to figure out how the standard specifies promotion)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons If the posted code and output is correct, it *is* being promoted to an `int`.  Although as I read the rules, I also think that might be wrong and it *should* be promoted to a `short`.  This might be a compiler bug.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons `a+c` has not been assigned to any target variable. Arithmetic calculations are promoted to `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane When I read through those rules, when I start with `short + char`, I wind up with `short`, not `int`.  What am I missing?

Comment: This is not a type conversion to another variable type; there is no target variable type. Arithmetical calculations are promoted to `int` (to lessen the likelihood that intermediate values overflow) but I don't know the reference.

Comment: 5.1.2.3 para 11 EXAMPLE 2 In executing the fragment `char c1, c2; /* ... */ c1 = c1 + c2;` *the "integer promotions" require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to int size and then add the two ints and truncate the sum.* But there is no truncation here because the destination is unknown.

Comment: @WeatherVane If you don't mind I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @AndrewHenle please do.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` returns the size of the object representation after it has been evaluated. The expression `c+a` apparently returns an int, which is four bytes.  I think what you are looking for is:

`sizeof(c) + sizeof(a)`

Answer (score 3):

When integral types like `char`, `short int`, `bool` take less number of bytes than `int`, then these data types are automatically promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` when an operation is performed on them.

**C11 §6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers**

> If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned   int. These are called the
>   integer promotions. 58)

So, `c+a` are converted to type `int` and the result has this common type of operands that is `int`.

Also, the behaviour of your code is **undefined**, because you have used the wrong format specifier.

So, use `%zu` instead of `%d` because `sizeof()` returns `size_t` and `size_t` is `unsigned`.

**C11 Standard: §7.21.6.1: Paragraph 9:**

> **If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.** 225) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

For the mathematically inclined (and because it occurred to me to wonder when such a thing might ever be true):

The misapprehension that is OP is labouring under is that

f(x) + f(y) = f(x+y)

which is certainly not true for `sizeof()` for the reasons Tom points out in the comments.

The class of functions for which it *is* true are called [Additive Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_map)

Typical examples include maps between rings, vector spaces, or modules that preserve the additive group.

Comment: Fun but in "C", sizeof is a compile-time operator and they are not functions. Back to abstract algebra, the two "+" operators are different, one being on unsigned integer values and the other being on types so I don't think you have a map.

Comment: @tom-blodget yep was just having some fun with a silly question :) Updated the answer to reference your input.